# How to use JsonSerializable on function in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization, json-serialization

I want to improve the functioning of my application a bit using json_serializable. I use the https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php Here is the code for the model that is currently in the app.
`

```
class CocktailModel {
  final String name;
  final String category;
  final String alcoholic;
  final String glassType;
  final String pictureUrl;
  final String instructions;
  final List<IngredientModel> ingredientsList;

  CocktailModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.category,
    required this.alcoholic,
    required this.glassType,
    required this.pictureUrl,
    required this.instructions,
    required this.ingredientsList,
  });

  CocktailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['strDrink'] ?? '',
        category = json['strCategory'] ?? '',
        alcoholic = json['strAlcoholic'] ?? '',
        glassType = json['strGlass'] ?? '',
        pictureUrl = json['strDrinkThumb'] ?? '',
        instructions = json['strInstructions'] ?? '',
        ingredientsList = _getIngredients(json);

  static List<IngredientModel> _getIngredients(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) {
    List<IngredientModel> ingredientsList = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
      if (json['strIngredient$i'] == null) {
        continue;
      }
      if (json['strMeasure$i'] == null) {
        continue;
      }
      ingredientsList.add(
        IngredientModel(
          name: json['strIngredient$i'],
          mesure: json['strMeasure$i'],
        ),
      );
    }
    return ingredientsList;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, in one case I don't know how to use it correctly because I have a certain function (_getIngredients) created that adds more ingredients and measures to me in the right way.
How do I need to write this _getIngredients function so that json_serializable generates the right g.dart file??

I tried to do this in this way, but unfortunately I get null from the api:

```
import 'package:random_cocktail_app/domain/models/ingredient_model.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'cocktail_model.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CocktailModel {
  @JsonKey(name: 'strDrink')
  final String name;

  @JsonKey(name: 'strCategory')
  final String category;

  @JsonKey(name: 'strAlcoholic')
  final String alcoholic;

  @JsonKey(name: 'strGlass')
  final String glassType;

  @JsonKey(name: 'strDrinkThumb')
  final String pictureUrl;

  @JsonKey(name: 'strInstructions')
  final String instructions;


  **@JsonKey(fromJson: _getIngredients)
  final List<IngredientModel> ingredientsList;**

  CocktailModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.category,
    required this.alcoholic,
    required this.glassType,
    required this.pictureUrl,
    required this.instructions,
    required this.ingredientsList,
  });

  factory CocktailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$CocktailModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CocktailModelToJson(this);

  **static List<IngredientModel> _getIngredients(
    Map<String, dynamic> json,
  ) {
    List<IngredientModel> ingredientsList = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
      if (json['strIngredient$i'] == null) {
        continue;
      }
      if (json['strMeasure$i'] == null) {
        continue;
      }
      ingredientsList.add(
        IngredientModel(
          name: json['strIngredient$i'],
          mesure: json['strMeasure$i'],
        ),
      );
    }
    return ingredientsList;
  }**
}
```

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me solve my problem :)

Comment: can you provide example `json` data?

Comment: @pmatatias If you're concerned with what data comes in from the API then, for example: "strDrink": "Pina Colada",, "strIngredient1": "Light rum", "strIngredient2": "Coconut milk", "strIngredient3": "Pineapple", "strMeasure1": "3 oz ", "strMeasure2": "3 tblsp ", "strMeasure3": "3 tblsp ",
That's what the _getIngredients function was created for, to get the right amounts of ingredients and measures (in this example, we have 3 ingredients and 3 measures, and there can be, for example, 4 or 5 etc.) However, I just don't know how to do the same logic (_getIngredients) for using json_serializable